# any C/C++ refactoring tool based on libclang? (even simplest "toy example" )

Tags: c++, refactoring, llvm, clang

As I've pointed out - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587140/any-tutorial-on-how-to-use-clang-for-syntax-highlighting-and-code-completion/7250322#7250322) - it seems clang's libclang should be great for implementing the hard task that is C/C++ code analysis and modifications ([check out video presentation and slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587140/any-tutorial-on-how-to-use-clang-for-syntax-highlighting-and-code-completion/7250322#7250322)).

Do you know of **any** C/C++ refactoring tool based on libclang ?

"Any" includes even simple alpha state project, with support of one refactoristation technique. It can be without preprocessor support. As an example of the functionally about which I'm talking: changing method names, whether it supports multiple files or only one file at a time. You might be wondering what the goal is of asking for even small working examples My thought is that *creating a list of code examples and small tools that are in one place will provide a better resource to learn how to implement refactorisation with libclang*. I believe that from simple projects might grow bigger projects - in a proper opensource manner :).

Comment: Even with great infrastructure, that's a lot harder than it looks. As a first step, what do you about the preprocessor?

Comment: Ok, I agree it's not trivial task. It was overkill on my side that I've wrote "easily". Please, let me correct this into another adjective. My point was - that with libclang it could be much easier, but I agree - still not easy.

Comment: Arguably Clang *is* that simple refactoring project, and it does appear to be growing.

Comment: Is your question more focused on Clang as C/C++ refactoring tool, or are you more interested in C/C++ refactoring tools, of which Clang might be an interesting candidate?

Comment: I am more interested on C/C++ refactoring tools made with `libclang`. I would love to jump into their sources and contribute.

Comment: There is a [somewhat similar question on the Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2705/11844), apparently based on this one.

Answer (score 24):

Clang contains a library called "CIndex" which was developed, I believe, for doing code completion in IDEs. It can also be used for parsing C++ and walking the AST, but doesn't have anything in the way of refactoring. See Eli Bendersky's article [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/).

I have started such a project recently: [cmonster](http://blog.awilkins.id.au/2011/10/c-source-to-source-translation.html). It's a Python-based API for parsing C++ (using libclang), analyzing the AST, with an interface for "rewriting" (i.e. inserting/removing/modifying source ranges). There's no nice way (yet) for doing things like modifying function names and having that translated into source-modifications, but it wouldn't be terribly difficult to do that.

I have not yet created a release with this functionality (although it's in the github repo), as I'm waiting for llvm/clang 3.0 to be released.

Also, I should point out a couple of things:

- The code is very rough, calling it alpha would be perhaps generous.
- I'm by no means an expert on this subject (unlike, say, Dr. Ira Baxter over there).

Adjust expectations appropriately.

**Update:** cmonster 0.2 has been released, which includes the described features. Check it out [on Github](https://github.com/axw/cmonster).

Answer (score 15):

Google have been working on a tooling library for Clang. [In since the 3.2 release](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/branches/release_32/include/clang/ASTMatchers/). It includes a ASTMatchers library so you can just build up a query and don't have to walk the AST.

There is a [great video talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuIOGfcOH0k) on the subject that walks through a simple rename example. (This is from the same guy as the [MapReduce talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVbDzTM21BQ) posted above but is newer and more about a simple practical implementation rather than the internal design and enterprise scale stuff Google have going on).

The source for that example that renames a method is available in the [tooling branch](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/branches/tooling/examples/rename-method/). It may be somewhere in the trunk but I can't find it. Also Rename the getDeclAs function to getNodesAs as the other is [apparently deprecated](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ast__matchers_1_1BoundNodes.html#a748143159c4cf50c2b01ed799f62d337).). There is a more [advanced example that removes duplicated c_str calls](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/trunk/remove-cstr-calls/) (which is in trunk and someone posted above).

Here is documentation for [LibASTMatchers](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html) and [LibTooling](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html).

EDIT: Some better docs for ASTMatcher. [Here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html) and [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html).

EDIT: [Google are now working on something called Clangd](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTEyMTE) which aims to be some kind of Clang server for refactoring.

Comment: link is gone. see [RemoveCStrCalls.cpp on github](https://github.com/search?q=path%3A**%2FRemoveCStrCalls.cpp&type=code)

Answer (score 8):

Google made a Clang based refactoring tool for their C++ code base and plans to release it. I don't know the current state of the project, but you can see this demo presented on the 2011 LLVM Developers Meeting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVbDzTM21BQ.

Also, XCode's (4+) built-in auto-completion and refactoring functions are based on libclang.

Answer (score 6):

Not open source, but has been used to carry out very non-toy [massive automated refactoring of C++ programs](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/WCRE05.pdf):
our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).   DMS is a "library" (we called it a "toolkit") of facilities on can compose to achieve anlaysis and/or automated translation.

Relevant to C++, DMS provides at this point in time:

- Full C++11 parser, constructing the AST and able to regenerate source code accurately
  including comments, with a complete preprocessor
- Full C++ parser with name and type resolution for C++ (ANSI, GNU, MS Visual C++)
- Control flow analysis for C++
- Source-to-source transformations
- Partially complete "rename" machinery (see discussion below)

What I can say from experience is that C++ is a bitch of a language to transform.

We continue to work on it, and are completing a reliable renaming tool.  Even this is hard; a key problem is the name-shadowing problem.  You have a local variable X, and a reference to Y inside that scope; you attempt to rename Y to X and discover that the local variable "captures" the access.  It is amazing how many namespaces and capture types you have to worry about in C++.  And this is needed as a foundation for many other refactorings.

EDIT Feb 2014:  Full C++14 parser, control flow analysis, local data flow analysis

Comment: I have no idea why I am the first to up-vote this answer.  If the asker wants to limits to open source, they should say so.  I believe you when you say C++ is a very hard language to "understand" via parser/machine: What does this say about Eclipse's CDT with rename feature?  Never used Eclipse for C++, but I have for Java, along with its wealth of refactoring tools -- way, way simpler, of course.

Comment: To be fair, OP asked for Clang-related answer, and my answer isn't Clang related. I added it because the implications seemed to be that nothing could do refactoring on C++, which just isn't true.

Answer (score 6):

This may be a bit 'meta', but there's an example thats written in clang as a tool to run on clang (although, there's more to it than just that.

[RemoveCStrCalls.cpp](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/Tooling/RemoveCStrCalls/RemoveCStrCalls.cpp?revision=132374&view=markup&pathrev=132374)

```
//  This file implements a tool that prints replacements that remove redundant
//  calls of c_str() on strings.
//
//  Usage:
//  remove-cstr-calls <cmake-output-dir> <file1> <file2> ...
//
//  Where <cmake-output-dir> is a CMake build directory in which a file named
//  compile_commands.json exists (enable -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS in
//  CMake to get this output).
//
//  <file1> ... specify the paths of files in the CMake source tree. This path
//  is looked up in the compile command database. If the path of a file is
//  absolute, it needs to point into CMake's source tree. If the path is
//  relative, the current working directory needs to be in the CMake source
//  tree and the file must be in a subdirectory of the current working
//  directory. "./" prefixes in the relative files will be automatically
//  removed, but the rest of a relative path must be a suffix of a path in
//  the compile command line database.
//
//  For example, to use remove-cstr-calls on all files in a subtree of the
//  source tree, use:
//
//    /path/in/subtree $ find . -name '*.cpp'|
//        xargs remove-cstr-calls /path/to/source
```

Comment: it can be treated as kind of refactoring. For sure, it might be usefull code for people interested in refactoring. So +1 :)

Comment: link is gone. see [RemoveCStrCalls.cpp on github](https://github.com/search?q=path%3A**%2FRemoveCStrCalls.cpp&type=code)

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/lukhnos/refactorial is based on clang and claims

> Transforms Provided
>
> Accessor: Synthesize getters and setters for designated member
>   variables
>
> MethodMove: Move inlined member function bodies to the implementation
>   file
>
> ExtractParameter: promote a function variable to a parameter to that
>   function
>
> TypeRename: Rename types, including tag types (enum, struct, union,
>   class), template classes, Objective-C types (class and protocol),
>   typedefs and even bulit-in types (e.g. unsigned to uint32_t)
>
> RecordFieldRename: Rename record (struct, union) fields, including C++
>   member variables
>
> FunctionRename: Rename functions, including C++ member functions

Works via specifications in a YAML configuration file. I haven't tried it out (yet).

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to develop your own plugin for GCC, or to develop a [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension to do your task. But extending GCC (or Clang) requires understanding the internal representations of these compilers (Gimple & Tree for GCC) and this require some work. MELT is a high-level domain specific language to extend GCC.

Comment: There's several other open source foundations for C++ refactoring, including Eclipse CDT.

Comment: @IraBaxter - Good point of mentioning Eclipse CDT. The problem I've seen was, I haven't seen command line tool or library that provides such functionality. So I suppose Eclipse CDT can not work standalone, but as "clickable gui tool", what limits applications - especially when thinking about automation in refactoring.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki:  Well, if Eclipse can gui-click to implement functions, there's clearly machinery inside does those functions and with some(?) effort one could expose them as a command line tool.  Is that your goal?  It isn't clear from the way you posed your question.   If it is, I'd expect you to appreciate my answer.

Comment: @IraBaxter My point is - if someone knows about Eclipse CDT exposed as library or command line tool: please let us know :).

Comment: @IraBaxter I don't know how it is now, but I've tried to play with Eclipse CDT about 2009-2010. I remember it felt not suitable for using as "refactoring componend" for batch tasks and/or editor agnostic component suitable to prepare plugins for vim, emacs, and what someone might like. That's why I ask mainly about libclang - I've found it's api interesting.

Comment: Gcc is, I think, unusable for refactoring because its parser does code transformations during AST generation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not refactoring, but completion, but might be useful:

- [clang complete : Use of Clang for completing C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302)