# Access the compiler AST for C++ classes and function signatures for automatically binding to Lua

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, compiler-construction, clang++, luabind

I use Luabind to manually bind my classes to Lua. Each time I write a new class, I  do this binding manually. Is it possible to get a C++ compiler to output the details of a class, its functions, function signatures and overloaded functions' information as XML?

Or write a plugin for a C++ compiler to access this information? I could then use this information to generate the binding automatically.

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9024163/120163

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ira. I decided to go with CLANG for parsing my C++ code and generating the bindings.