# How do I generate an AST from a string of C++ using Clang?

Tags: c++, parsing, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to use Clang to manipulate C++ source-code, but I am having trouble discovering the API.

I would like to take a string of C++ source-code and generate an AST from it; something like:

```
auto myAst = clang::parse("auto x = 1 + 1;");
```

Is there a minimal working example of this?

Comment: You can try with this tutorial: https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/wiki/TutorialOrig

Comment: An alternativethat can parse arbitrary fragments of C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9024163/120163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the next code:

```
std::unique_ptr<ASTUnit> AST(tooling::buildASTFromCode("auto x = 1 + 1;"));
TranslationUnitDecl *DC = AST->getASTContext().getTranslationUnitDecl();
if (DC) {
   llvm::errs() << "---------dump begin----------\n";
   DC->dump();
   llvm::errs() << "---------dump end----------\n";
}
```